# get the aria-checked attribute in li

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying the below, here: I was using this logic before grabbing ids just fine, now it is erroring with the '`aria-checked`' seemingly because of the dash. Any pointers?

```
  let inputs = document.querySelectorAll('li[role=treeitem]');
  userA[username].userAchkData = [];

      inputs.forEach(function(li){
         userA[username].userAchkData.push({ id: li.getAttribute('aria-checked'), checked: li.checked });
      });
```

The relevant mark-up is like so:

```
<li role="treeitem" class="k-item" data-uid="xxx" aria-checked="true" aria-selected="false" aria-expanded="false" data-expanded="false" id="appTV"><div class="k-mid"><span class="k-checkbox-wrapper" role="presentation"><input type="checkbox" tabindex="-1" id="_111" class="k-checkbox"><span class="k-checkbox-label checkbox-span"></span></span><span class="k-in">(Private)</span></div></li>
```

**Context:** I am trying to save the state of checkbox states, the checkbox states are derived from rather the `aria-checked` is true or false.

And below is how I'm loading it later: **(current error is here)**

```
  inputs.forEach(function(li){ 
    console.log(li);
    if (li.id) { 
        document.getElementById(input.id).checked = input.getAttribute('aria-checked');
       // I have also tried
       // document.getElementById(li.id).getAttribute('aria-checked') = input.getAttribute('aria-checked'); 
       // both returs li.getAttribute is not a function
      }
    });
```

---

Comment: what is `username`

Comment: that works fine, that is just a object key I am using from the users username. This logic worked just fine on input and ids, I think it's a syntax thing with finding aria-checked with the dash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [**Element.getAttribute()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute) to access the custom/non-standard attribute's value:

> The `getAttribute()` method of the Element interface returns the value of a specified attribute on the element. If the given attribute does not exist, the value returned will either be null or "" (the empty string).

```
userA[username].userAchkData.push({ id: input.getAttribute('aria-checked'), checked: input.checked });
```

**Update:** You are trying to set the `checked` property of the *li* elements itself which does not have any such property. You should find the checkbox inside the *li*. I also think you do need the *if* condition here:

```js
let inputs = document.querySelectorAll('li[role=treeitem]');
inputs.forEach(function(input){ 
  input.querySelector('[type=checkbox]').checked = input.getAttribute('aria-checked');
});
```

```html
<li role="treeitem" class="k-item" data-uid="xxx" aria-checked="true" aria-selected="false" aria-expanded="false" data-expanded="false" id="appTV"><div class="k-mid"><span class="k-checkbox-wrapper" role="presentation"><input type="checkbox" tabindex="-1" id="_111" class="k-checkbox"><span class="k-checkbox-label checkbox-span"></span></span><span class="k-in">(Private)</span></div></li>
```

Comment: Hey thanks, this worked on my first reference when saving the data. But when retrieved it it's failing within input.getAttribute.. is not a function. I updated the OP, any ideas how to call it after?

Comment: So this looks great! I am still getting querySelector is not a function  for some reason :/ maybe it's do to the local storage aspect? I've updated the post with my fully updated code.

Comment: I suppose you have answered the original question at hand: I have opened a new one with the remaining issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60326366/save-checkboxes-via-aria-check-attribute-then-recheck-them-localstorage